# How to share data-structure definition between kernel modules and user-application?

Tags: c, linux, kernel, driver

I would like to develop a device-driver on linux(written in C) and a user-space library wrapping all functions provided by my device-driver (also written in C). Just to make it more clear, my library wil provide the following methods:

- `int myOpen();`
- `void myClose();`
- `mySetConf(MyconfStruct conf)`
- etc.

The function will use the file associated to my device-driver, in particular:

- `myOpen` will call the `open()` of my device-driver
- `myClose` will call the `close()` of my device-driver
- `mySetConf` will call the `ioctl()` of my device driver and pass the `myConfStruct` as a parameter to configure the device-driver using `ioctl()`.

assume `myConfStruct` is a simple structure containing something like this:

```c
typedef struct {
    uint16_t var1;
    uint8_t var2;
} myConfStruct;
```

I would like the `myConfStruct` to be a structure shared between both my user-application (library) and my kernel-driver using a single header.
Are there any best-practice while doing this?
I would like to have the structure defined into only one file, having it defined in multiple files seems to be quite error-prone if i plan on changing it in the future, but I understood that I should not include `<linux/types.h>` inside my user files and I shouldn't use `<stdint.h>` inside my device-driver.
So another question is also, how can I define the interface between a module and the user-application so that who is implementing the application is not forced to include any linux header?

Comment: Hmm. [This linux/types.h](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/tools/include/linux/types.h) itself has `#include <stdint.h>` in it, so I don't see the problem of your driver code also doing that.

Comment: Unfortunately by simply including stdint.h in the shared header filde between kernel and user-application i receive an "error: no include path in which to search for stdint.h" . I'm pretty sure there is no error in compilation since I'm using default compilation recipes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are creating is a character device.  The kernel documentation includes a specific section, [the Linux driver implementer's guide](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/driver-api/index.html), you should also read.  Specifically, the [ioctl based interfaces](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/driver-api/ioctl.html) section, which also describes some of the considerations necessary (regarding alignment and 64-bit fields).

As to header files, see [KernelHeaders](https://kernelnewbies.org/KernelHeaders) article at kernelnewbies.org.

> I would like to have the structure defined into only one file, having it defined in multiple files seems to be quite error-prone if i plan on changing it in the future.

No.  You do specify the headers in two separate files: one for use in-kernel, and the other for use by userspace.

Kernel-userspace interface should be **stable**.  You should take care to design your data structure so that you can extend it if necessary; preferably by adding some padding reserved for future use and required to be initialized to zero, and/or a version number at the beginning of the structure.  Later versions **must** support all previous versions of the structure as well.  Even if it is only a "toy" or "experimental" device driver, it is best to learn to do it right from the get go.  This stuff is much, much harder to learn to "add afterwards"; I'm talking from deep experience here.

As a character device, you should also be prepared for the driver to be compiled on other architectures besides the one you are developing on.  Even byte order ("endianness") can vary, although all Linux architectures are currently either [ILP32 or LP64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LP64#64-bit_data_models).

Also remember that there are several hardware architectures, including x86-64, that support both 64-bit and 32-bit userspace.  So, even if you *believe* your driver will ever be used on x86-64, you cannot really assume the userspace is 64-bit (and not 32-bit).  Look at existing code to see how it is done right; I recommend using e.g. [bootlin's elixir](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source) to browse the Linux kernel sources.

Kernel-side header file should use `__s8`, `__u8`, `__s16`, `__u16`, `__s32`, `__u32`, `__s64`, or `__u64`.  For pointers, use `__u64`, and `u64_to_user_ptr()`.

Userspace-side header file should use `<stdint.h>` types (`int8_t`, `uint8_t`, `int16_t`, `uint16_t`, `int32_t`, `uint32_t`, `int64_t`, `uint64_t`) and `uint64_t` for pointers.  Use a cast via `(uintptr_t)` for the conversion, i.e. `ptr = (void *)(uintptr_t)u64;` and `u64 = (uintptr_t)ptr`.

Ensure all members are naturally aligned.  This means that an *N*-bit member is preceded by *k*×*N* bits of other members, where *k* is either zero or a positive integer.  Thus, if your structure needs an unsigned and a signed 8-bit integer (one for version, one for *foo*), an 16-bit signed integer (*bar*), and a 64-bit unsigned integer (*baz*), considering the version should be first, you'll probably want

```c
struct kernel_side {
    __u8   version;
    __s8   foo;
    __u16  bar;
    __u32  padding;
    __u64  baz;
};

struct userspace_side {
    uint8_t   version;
    int8_t    foo;
    uint16_t  bar;
    uint32_t  padding;
    uint64_t  baz;
};
```

You can also have character arrays and such, but do note that a single ioctl data block is limited to 8191 bytes or less in length.

If you spend some time designing your interface structures, you'll find that careful design will avoid annoying issues like compat_ support (making them just simple wrappers).  Personally, I end up creating a test version with a userspace test program to see what works best, and only then decide on the data structures.

Comment: So, just to be sure that I understand this correctly. If I want to enable the application programmer, to use the ioctl that I have implemented I need to define another header file to use only in user-space. Same thing for the structures that I plan to receive by my ioctl calls, or ma i missing something?

Comment: @GionataBenelli: Correct.  You want to create one header file, using `<stdint.h>` types (as opposed to `int`, `long`), that is used by userspace applications.  A separate header file, only used during your kernel driver compilation, is needed to describe the structure in kernel type terms.  This is normal, and common.

Comment: Looks like it is impossible to create a single header file that will be shared across the device driver code and the applications. Is the `version` member the best way to synchronize the application and the kernel headers? I wonder if we can do that at the compile time.